# How to Merge these 2 Select Statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

How to merge these 2 select statements so that 3 columns are returned?

the first select only returns text values whereas the second select returns a table column value. If the second table returns no value, still the first select should have value and the name column can be null

```
SELECT 'column1', 'column2'

SELECT Name
FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE ID = @id
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT 'column1', 'column2', Name
FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE ID = @id
```

This will return a row for each row with a matching `ID` in the table.

---

Update:

This query will do exactly what you want:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM [dbo].[TableName] WHERE ID = @id) = 0
BEGIN
 SELECT 'column1', 'column2', NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'column1', 'column2', Name
    FROM [dbo].[TableName]
    WHERE ID = @id
END
```

Comment: not exactly, that doesn't return any result if no record is found in the Table. I'd need to return the 2 first columsn and e.g. have null for Name if no value is found in the table.

Comment: @William - Can you explain why you are doing this in the DB? Looks like something to do in application code (if no values exists in the DB do x otherwise do y).

Comment: sorry, I can't explain why as it's complicated. I'd just need to know how, thanks.

Comment: @William - Well... without context, it is impossible to come with a better overall solution (if one exists).

Comment: @William - Yes, though my point about better overall solution still stands.

Answer (score 0):

this would be simpler, no need to duplicate the fixed columns:

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(255)

SELECT @name=Name FROM [dbo].[TableName] WHERE ID = @id 

SELECT 'column1', 'column2', @name AS 'Name'
```

Comment: But here you still have two _separate_ queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one query like this:

```
SELECT
  'column1',
  'column2',
  (
    SELECT Name
    FROM [dbo].[TableName]
    WHERE ID = @id
  ) AS 'Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as seems likely, there can only be at most one match then Andriy or William's solutions are the best. If for some strange reason Id isn't a primary key then the following will do what you want.

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2, t.Name
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 'column1' AS column1, 'column2' AS column2
  ) a
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TableName] t ON (t.ID = @Id)
```

I feel kinda dirty....